# I am dividing two XML elements using XSLT. I keep getting a NaN response after defining variables.

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XML and I am building a few Recipies using XML. I am using XSLT to transform the XML, however, I keep getting NaN as the response.

I want to create a calorie per serving output by diving the qty of servings, under yield and divide it by the qty of calories -- defined by  undernutrition. I am not sure that I am assigning numbers correctly.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

XML CODE:

```
<recipe>
  <head>
    <yield>
      <qty>7</qty>
        <unit>servings</unit>
    </yield> 
  </head>
  <nutrition>
    <nutrient>
      <n-name>calories</n-name>
        <qty>1200</qty>
    </nutrient>
  </nutrition>
</recipe>
```

XSLT CODE:

```
<xsl:template match="nutrient">
  <xsl:variable name="calorietotal" select="//nutrient[n-name='calories']/qty" />
  <xsl:variable name="servings" select="head[yield='serving']/qty" />

 <div class="ings">
     <div class="numcals">Calories Per Serving:</div>
        <xsl:value-of select="$calorietotal div $servings" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply your XPaths are not correct within the context of *nutrient* node and with slight misspelling. Consider below adjustments where division will not result as NaN.

```
<xsl:variable name="calorietotal" select="n-name[.='calories']/following-sibling::qty" />
<xsl:variable name="servings" select="/recipe/head/yield[unit='servings']/qty" />
```

Also, too, you are not exhaustively re-writing the tree so some unspecified node text renders in output such as "7 servings". Add another template to walk down the tree from root and only write a style for *nutrient* node. Even add output parameters for indentation and html method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/recipe">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="nutrition/nutrient"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nutrient">
    <xsl:variable name="calorietotal" select="n-name[.='calories']/following-sibling::qty"/>
    <xsl:variable name="servings" select="/recipe/head/yield[unit='servings']/qty"/>

    <div class="ings">
      <div class="numcals">Calories Per Serving:</div>
        <xsl:value-of select="$calorietotal div $servings"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Df/1)

Answer (score 0):

The `head` element is not a child of `nutrient` so the value of the $servings variable is an empty node-set, and converting an empty node-set to a number returns NaN.

When you use path expressions you need to understand the concept of the "current node", which is where selections are made from. In a template that matches the "nutrient" element, that element is the current node.

In future, when asking XSLT questions on StackOverflow, please be sure to say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Both are widely used, and they have many differences.